# Is it possible to return api response instead of model/database in rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am proudly say that i am completely newbie. I am trying to understand rest framework model-view relations. But, i have a question which is i couldn't find answer in docs.

I want to show some datas from outsources not my database. For example:

Receive a post parameters -->  SEND ANOTHER POST REQUEST TO ANOTHER SERVER --> RECEIVE RESPONSE and Return Json Response to client/visitor. All of trainings for models and showing items from database but what about if i want to show some data from another sources.

Thank you in advance. I will be appreciated if you can share some documentations with me.

Comment: Yes it's possible...

Comment: would you share a documentation with me i couldn't find.

Comment: `requests` is the standard library for making requests in Python https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/